# How many generations of Weasleys has Dumbledore seen in all his years in Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, albus-dumbledore

I'm just curious to know how many generations of Weasleys Dumbledore saw during his time at Hogwarts?

Comment: Several. At least two

Comment: "In all his years at Hogwarts" - including when he was a student?

Comment: All of them, I would assume. It's not like there's some other school they would be going to.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming "during his time at Hogwarts" refers to the time he taught at Hogwarts.

There is no clear answer, but I'll try to present what makes the most sense.

Let's start with when Dumbledore started teaching at Hogwarts:
Dumbledore was born [in 1881](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Albus_Dumbledore#Biography), meaning he started attending Hogwarts as a student in 1892, and finished in 1899. The earliest he could have started teaching at Hogwarts is a few years later, considering he was probably too young to start teaching immediately after he graduated, and that he had the whole story with Ariana and Grindelwald.

The Latest Dumbledore could've started teaching is 1910:
Newt Scamander was born in [1897](https://twitter.com/FantasticBeasts/status/915607503630565376), Meaning his 3rd year in Hogwarts was 13 years later in 1910. In *The Crimes of Grindelwald*, there is a Boggart Scene with Dumbledore teaching Newt. Boggarts are taught in 3rd year, therefore **Dumbledore started teaching at Hogwarts between the early 1900-1910**.

Let's look at the Weasley family: Arthur Weasley's Father, Septimus, married [Cedrella Black](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Cedrella_Black#cite_note-1). Cedrella had an older sister born in 1915 and a younger sister born in 1919, so it's safe to say she was born in 1917. Assuming Septimus was around her age, he attended Hogwarts from 1928-1935. We now know of 3 Weasley generations that Dumbledore taught: Ron's generation, Arthur's generation, and Septimus's generation.

Could Dumbledore have taught Septimus's father? (I'll call him X just so it's easier). If he had, X would've been at the latest ~32 when he had Septimus, (If X's last year in Hogwarts was in the early 1900's- ~1902,) making sense that Dumbledore taught him in Hogwarts.

But it also works out that Dumbledore didn't teach him. Assuming he didn't, X could've had Septimus as early as ~25 (If X's last year in Hogwarts was in 1909, the year before the latest possible date for Dumbledore beginning to teach at Hogwarts).

So, in conclusion, **Dumbledore taught 3 or 4 Weasley generations in Hogwarts.**